# Save a double matrix as an image file in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, type-conversion, png, tiff

I have a matrix `sig_matrix` of data type double, the values are like:

```
3,0450  3,0450  3,0450
2,6200  2,6050  2,5900
2,5250  2,5200  2,5150
2,3800  2,3800  2,3650
2,6050  2,6650  2,7350
```

I need to save as an image file, but the problem is: image types like jpg, png only accepts integer data (uint8, uint16), but I really need to save the data as double.

I tried to save as a TIF file using the code below:

```
t = Tiff('test.tif', 'w8');
setTag(t,'Photometric',Tiff.Photometric.RGB);
setTag(t,'ImageLength',length(sig_matrix));
setTag(t,'ImageWidth',length(sig_matrix));
setTag(t,'BitsPerSample',64);
setTag(t,'SamplesPerPixel',3);
setTag(t,'SampleFormat', 3);
setTag(t,'PlanarConfiguration',Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);
setTag(t,'Compression',Tiff.Compression.None);
write(t,repmat(sig_matrix, [1 1 3]));
close(t);
```

It worked, but then I tried to convert this file to yuv (using `ffmpeg` for example) but I got an error (Invalid TIFF header to be more specific).

So, I need to save a double matrix as a image file and then convert to yuv.

Anyone could help me please?

Obs.: I can't use `mat2gray` or something like that because I need that specific double data to convert to yuv

Comment: Why don't you find the range of your values and map them onto an integer colour scale?

Comment: But when I convert to yuv, the input need to be in double

Comment: `ffmpeg` will expect integer pixel values, I'm sure. Most software does. TIFF files with floating-point values are quite rare. Why do you say that conversion to yuv require doubles?

Comment: yuv doesn't require double data, but my project does. I am getting the data from a biological signal, so to not lose any kind of information I need to use as double data type.
I tried to use TIFF because like I said, most of image format only accepts uint8 or uint16, I thought TIFF would be a good alternative to store the data.

Comment: If you need to retain full precision then you probably want to look into other formats for saving the data. This will depend on which language you want to do the processing in. For example, if you save it using MATLAB's `save` function (as a .mat) then you can load that in python using scipy's `loadmat` function. A more brute-force method would be to use `fwrite` to write all the raw bytes which can pretty easily be read in most languages.

Comment: As far as the YUV conversion goes, the [equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to/from_RGB) are pretty straight forward and you can implement in MATLAB before saving.